# Get pages based on pagename and should be located within the page tree

Tags: wordpress, timber

My website is based on pages only. I have the structure like this:

```
New
- Companies
  * Company1
  * Company2
Old
- Companies
  * Company3
  * Company4
```

When I go to site.com/new I want to list Company1, Company2. When I go to site.com/old, I want to list Company3, Company4

When I had only one 'companies' page (new->companies), this worked for me. As soon as I added old->companies, it stopped working because it didn't take into account the parent id.

```
$context['companies'] = new Timber\Post( 'companies' );
```

So I tried to select like this but it doesn't work:

```
// current page site.com/new

$timber_post     = new Timber\Post();

$args = array(
    'post_type'   => 'page',
    'post_parent__in' => array( $timber_post->id ),
    'pagename' => 'companies'
);

$context['companies'] = new Timber\PostQuery( $args );
```

How do I select the companies based within the same page tree?

I also stumbled upon another issue. I'm trying to add related pages via twig. I'm using YARPP plugin. When I include like this:
{{ function('related_pages') }}

I get the output twice. I mean:

"Related posts:
a
b
c

Related posts:
a
b
c
"

I did some research and it seems they you get the same issue if you use it in php files like this:

echo related_posts(); // outputs twice

related_posts(); // outputs once

How do I fix this within twig templates?

Thanks

Comment: I managed to fix the second issue.

ob_start();
$contact['related'] = related_posts();
ob_end_clean();

in my twig file I call it {{ related }}

Answer (score 0):

If you use the following query on the page `/new`, then it will probably return only one page, the `/new/companies` page.

```php
$args = array(
    'post_type'   => 'page',
    'post_parent__in' => array( $timber_post->id ),
    'pagename' => 'companies'
);

$context['companies'] = new Timber\PostQuery( $args );
```

To get Company 1 and Company 2, you would have to run that query on the `new/companies` page.

WordPress only allows you to select direct child and sibling pages in `WP_Query`. And to get the parent page, you can obviously use `$post->post_parent`. But it’s not possible to select from a whole page tree. What you could do to make this work is

- to write two queries. The first one would select the correct Companies page, and the second one would select the Companies from that page.
- to write a recursive function that would build a page tree no matter how deep your hierarchy is.

The bad thing is that you would have to either run multiple queries or use a query that selects all pages to build a tree. This is always a performance impact. In this case, however it’s probably not so bad.

But: do you actually need a separate Companies page under New and Old? Or could you change your page structure to the following?

```
New Companies
- Company1
- Company2
Old Companies
- Company3
- Company4
```

Because in that case, it would work with the query you already have.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to dig into my issue. I tried playing around with recursive solutions but I ended up with my initial code. It seems I had one issue why I didn't get the results as expected, I checked WP Query manual and changed the query param 'pagename' to 'name' instead.

Regarding the structure change, I kept the same structure because of the links I prefer to be shown.

Comment: Just wanted to updated that there is the wordpress function to get all ancestors. $ancestors = get_post_ancestors( $parent ); which I'm utilizing now.

Comment: Cool you’ve found that solution :)